# Combine the results while querying in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am struggling to querying in Django as expected.I have multiple models that are Profile, Education, Address and Social Media. Education, Address and Social Media and related with Profile by foreign key and OnoToOne relation. I want the query results that list of profiles and each profile should contain relevant
educations (as list), addresses (as list) and social media (as dictionary).

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class ORMProfile(models.Model):
    profile_photo = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_photo = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ORMEducation(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(ORMProfile, on_delete=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    school_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ORMSocialMedia(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(ORMProfile, on_delete=True)
    linked_in = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ORMAddress(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(ORMProfile, on_delete=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I am expecting the result is list of profile that each profile includes educations, addresses and social_media. (given below)

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "profile_photo": "google.com",
    "cover_photo": "facbook.com",
    "first_name": "Uzama",
    "last_name": "",
    "bio": "",
    "gender": "",
    "dob": null,
    "education": [],
    "address": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T09:12:13.859562+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T09:12:13.859615+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T09:12:33.485102+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T09:12:33.485167+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T09:13:28.909262+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T09:13:28.909325+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T09:13:40.228271+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T09:13:40.228369+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T10:27:31.060495+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T10:27:31.060565+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T10:27:59.089120+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T10:27:59.089171+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "profile_id": 2,
            "street": "23",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-16T10:28:25.406798+00:00",
            "modified_at": "2019-12-16T10:28:25.406869+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "social_media": {
        "id": 3,
        "profile_id": 2,
        "linked_in": "linkedin.lk",
        "facebook": "Hello",
        "twitter": "",
        "instagram": "",
        "created_at": "2019-12-15T14:20:40.183078+00:00",
        "modified_at": "2019-12-16T10:58:30.338692+00:00"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-12-15T10:36:56.538900+00:00",
    "modified_at": "2019-12-18T09:28:07.087380+00:00"
}]
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Serializers are the solution to your problem.

Comment: You can use `property` or just nested serializers will also do the job

Comment: Can you add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-property) you can acheive this. Here we are using reverse relationship. `Many = True` because you may have multiple associations.

```
class ORMProfile(models.Model):
    profile_photo = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_photo = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    @property                            #<----add this block
    def education(self):
        from .serializers import ORMProfileSerializer   # import your relevant serializer class
        return ORMProfileSerializer(self.ormeducation_set.all(), many=True).data   #reverse relationship
```

Comment: Than You. I got what I want from your answer.